# How to read an email(outlook) without spying in Blue Prism

Tags: excel, outlook, automation, blueprism, rpa

Blue Prism: I'm trying to read an email(outlook), Which contains the information about the status of a task, name and a table with multiple headers. I should save the required information like name, status of the task in an Excel under the headers which were already written. It should all happen dynamically without spying the elements. Can anybody please elaborate the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got 2 options:

1. Use [the MAPIEx object](https://portal.blueprism.com/documents/mapiex-user-guide) for a back-end connection to your Outlook profile's mailbox. (See also: [MAPIEx installation guide](https://portal.blueprism.com/documents/mapiex-installation-guide-and-release-notes-206))
2. *v6.3 and later* Use the bundled Blue Prism-provided MS Outlook VBO, which has the following actions:

> - Delete Email
> - Forward Email
> - Get Received Items Advanced
> - Get Received Items Basic
> - Get Received Items Expert
> - Get Sent Items Advanced
> - Get Sent Items Basic
> - Get Sent Items Expert
> - Mark Email As Read
> - Mark Email As Unread
> - Move Email to Inbox Sub Folder
> - Reply to Email
> - Reply All to Email
> - Save Attachment Attachments
> - Save Email
> - Save Email As File